# C# PowerPoint 2013 deactivate automatically extended display

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-capture, powerpoint-2013

I'm working on a WPF project, for desktop screen capture, and it opens `.pptx` files. But when I'm about to click on PP13 to open one presentation it automatically extends display to show two views: pc display in presentation helper mode and the other one with the full slides.

I know I can disable it through File>Options>Advanced>Display but I'd like to do it with C#. I can't find any way so I hope someone knows if it can be done and has some sort of solution. Is it possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Talk to us about what you have tried.. any code samples? I understand what you're asking and am wanting to know what your powerpoint code is that doesn't work?

Comment: What my app only does is call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(item.Value);` to call default Windows Application for it's extension (`item.Value` it's a file).
I'm googling for some sort of PP13 Interop method or event to do that but no success at the time. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff759900(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Powerpoint must store the setting somewhere... use ProcMon to work out where...

Comment: I dont think you will find a setting in the PP13 *Interop* Object Model. You might get lucky with an *optional* parameter to display the presentation as you desire but changing a setting in an Office App (like Powerpoint) is usually a registry key. Use C# to change the registry key value, then Shell the presentation with `Process.Start` then revert the registry key back to what the user had it set with originally. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll try it and post the solution later (if I've lucky).